# How to find a regular and surjective $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n/Z^n$?

Tags: differential-geometry

> Give a regular and surjective $\mathcal{C}^\infty$ mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n.$
>
> Remark: Regualrity means that $Df_p$ is injective.

I understand that $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$ is the set of equivalence classes on $\mathbb{R}$ for the relation $$x \sim y \iff \exists z \in \mathbb{Z}^n : x = y +z$$

, i.e.

$$\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n = \big\{[x] \mid x\in \mathbb{R}/\sim \big\}.$$

The natural idea would now be to define $f$ as $f: x \mapsto [x]$, which is obviously surjective. However, I do not see how to argue that this map is $\mathcal{C}^\infty$, until now I have only used this in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For context: We have just done manifolds and charts in the lecture.

Could you please explain this to me?

Comment: How did your lecture define a $C^\infty$ map on manifolds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really think about what the smooth structure on $\Bbb{R}^n/\Bbb{Z}^n$ is defined to be; this is the essence of the exercise.

Define a map $\pi:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^n/\Bbb{Z}^n$ by $x\mapsto [x]$. Given $[x]$, choose a lift $y\in \Bbb{R}^n$ (i.e. such that $\pi(y) = [x]$) and let $U = B_{1/2}(y) = \{z\in \Bbb{R}^n:\lVert z-y\rVert < 1/2\}$. You can verify that $\pi$ maps $U$ homeomorphically onto its image, which is an open neighborhood of $[x]$ and in fact that this is a smooth coordinate chart for the smooth structure on $\Bbb{R}^n/\Bbb{Z}^n$. Define the associated coordinate chart centred at $[x]$ by $(\pi(U), y^1,\ldots, y^n)$. Then, we are done. Indeed, in these local coordinates $\pi$ is given by $(y^1,\ldots, y^n) \mapsto (y^1,\ldots, y^n)$ and so $df_y = \mathrm{Id}_n$.